# Using Session with Schedule

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2.29 and I've set up some scheduled commands.

One of them uses some methods used in my app through normal use (i.e., via a browser) and so the session is accessible.

However, when I try and run the command manually using `artisan schedule:run`, I get the following exception:
`Session store not set on request.`

The Session isn't being set (I suppose in the same vein as if a route were accessed without the web middleware), so is there a way to manually boot up the Session? I'd rather not rewrite my methods to not use it.

Comment: i don't think `Session` is meant to be used from a command. Can you explain more about the use of the `Session` in this case?

Comment: My `User`s have roles, and I have a method on the model to check if the user has a certain role. Since there may be several checks in one page request, I flashed the initial check's results so it could grab it straight from the session instead, rather than looking up the database each time (there could be around 30 checks per page load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to the session in CLI. Session is strictly connected with the web browser (client side) which doesn't make sense in command line.

If You need a local storage (for server side) You can try with cache driver.

Comment: Thanks for confirming I can't use the session with the CLI. I ended up changing what I used the session for by using the cache instead, but only caching for 1 minute. It's not ideal, but it works!